# App throws certain users right out upon click

Tags: ios, crash, sprite-kit

My 1st iOS game with SpriteKit has been released world wide in the App Store for free. The game supports iOS 7.0 & higher. Problem is, certain users, after downloading the game, go to open it up to play & get immediately kicked out. The game doesn't even have time to load up. My sisters iPhone 4S, for instance, installs & operates the game fine. But a co-worker with an iPhone 4S has this problem. I have absolutely no idea what is going on or how to begin trouble shooting this. Has this or anything similar happened to others? Can someone recommend some methods of going about debugging such matters? I don't have experience in doing so on my own.

To add a few extra about the game for clarification:
-Uses SpriteKit (& its physics simulation)
-Minimum support of iOS 7.0 (since not everyone upgraded to iOS 8 yet)
-Written in Objective-C (no Swift what-so-ever)
-Stupid simple game mechanics (barely any code & very few classes for simple stuff)
-Uses Game Center (Currently connected & saving high scores)
-Uses iAd (Works flawlessly)
-Uses uint64_t for categoryBitMask (don't know if int64 is supported by iPhones such as 4S or iPhone 5). Such an example of a categoryBitMask:

```
static const uint64_t playerCategory = 0x1 << 1;
```

P.S. Inside of my AppDelegate class I found a remnant bit of code that I forgot to remove before - NSUSerDefaults:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;
}
```

Could this have been the culprit? I don't know how to test this (co-worker unavailable from now on).

Comment: What version of iOS is crashing ? If it's an iOS 7 only crash, that might help you track it down.

Comment: That's the nutty part: I don't know. Nobody is telling me.

Comment: The accepted answer is a good step. Flurry analytics is another good option as it will give you information about crashes and what version of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug could be thrown from anywhere in your app. You should try to to use something like [TestFlight](https://www.testflightapp.com/) or [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com) to identify bug on remote devices. But keep in mind that these systems can not catch some very rare kind or bugs and you may need to ask your co-worker (or anybody else experiencing this bug) for device and watch crashlogs on it. Good luck.